# Using multiple BlocConsumer for the same bloc on the same page

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm using [BlocConsumer](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocConsumer-class.html) in 'MyButton' widget which is used in all items in a list.
When a user press a button, I want to redirect the user to another page based on which button the user clicked (in the below code, a button text is printed instead).

If I run this code, one click on a button prints all texts ("Press 1", "Press 2", "Press 3").
Is it because the exact same listener attached to MyButton widget 3 times and all the listeners are called whenever any of the buttons is clicked?
Does it mean that there should not be more than one widget for a bloc on the same page?

I can fix the code by moving BlocConsumer to wrap the Column instead of MyButton. Is this the right way to handle this issue? If that's the case, I have to wrap a larger widget in more complex situation. For example, if the same bloc is used for widgets in appbar and body, then I'll have to wrap the entire page with BlocConsumer.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(BlocProvider<MyBloc>(
    create: (BuildContext context) => MyBloc(),
    child: MaterialApp(
      home: Column(
        children: [
          MyButton(text: "Press 1"),
          MyButton(text: "Press 2"),
          MyButton(text: "Press 3"),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyButton({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<MyBloc, MyState>(
      listenWhen: (previous, current) {
        return true;
      },
      listener: (context, state) {
        print(text);
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return TextButton(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          child: Text(text),
          onPressed: () {
            context.read<MyBloc>().add(MyEvent());
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyEvent {}

class MyState {}

class MyBloc extends Bloc<MyEvent, MyState> {
  MyBloc() : super(MyState());

  @override
  Stream<MyState> mapEventToState(MyEvent event) async* {
    yield MyState();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle different clicks in `bloc`, you have to define events and states.

```
// events
class FirstClick extends Event{}

class SecondClick extends Event{}

class ThirdClick extends Event{}

// states
class FirstClickState extends State{}

class SecondClickState extends State{}

class ThirdClickState extends State{}

// bloc function 
class MyBloc extends Bloc<MyEvent, MyState> {
MyBloc() : super(MyState());

  @override
  Stream<MyState> mapEventToState(MyEvent event) async* {
    if(event is FirstClick){
      yield FirstClickState();
    }

    if(event is SecondClick){
      yield SecondClickState();
    }

    if(event is ThirdClick){
      yield ThirdClickState();
    }
  }  
}

// view definition
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(BlocProvider<MyBloc>(
    create: (BuildContext context) => MyBloc(),
    child: MaterialApp(
    home: Column(
      children: [
        MyButton(text: "Press 1", onPressed:() => BlocProvider.of<MyBloc>(context).add(FirstClick())),
        MyButton(text: "Press 2", onPressed:() => BlocProvider.of<MyBloc>(context).add(SecondClick())),
        MyButton(text: "Press 3", onPressed:() => BlocProvider.of<MyBloc>(context).add(ThirdClick())),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
const MyButton({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);

final String text;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return BlocConsumer<MyBloc, MyState>(
    listenWhen: (previous, current) {
      return true;
    },
    listener: (context, state) {
      if(state is FirstClickState){
        // go to where ever 
        Navigator.push(context, Somewhere());
      }
      
      if(state is SecondClickState){
        // go to where ever 
        Navigator.push(context, Somewhere());
      }

      if(state is ThirdClickState){
        // go to where ever 
        Navigator.push(context, Somewhere());
      }
    },
    builder: (context, state) {
      return TextButton(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        child: Text(text),
        onPressed: () {
          context.read<MyBloc>().add(MyEvent());
        },
      );
    },
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: My example only has 3 buttons but it can have much more than that.
Even worse, the buttons might not be the same type (e.g., button in AppBar and button in body).

Answer (score 0):

What I do in the case where you have an undefined count of pages, I use a Cubit with a state type of `int`. This allows you to have as many pages as you want, and the index of the page can be used as the cubit's state.

```dart
class PagesCubit extends Cubit<int> {
  PagesCubit() : super(0);

  void selectPage(int index) => emit(index);

}
```

in your code, you can use it this way.

```dart
BlocProvider<PagesCubit>(
  lazy: false,
  create: (BuildContext context) => PagesCubit(),
  child: BlocListener<PagesCubit, int>(
    listener: (context, state) {
      print(state); // expects int value
      //TODO: navigate to page
    },
    child: MaterialApp(
    home: Column(
        children: [
          MyButton(text: "Press 1"),
          MyButton(text: "Press 2"),
          MyButton(text: "Press 3"),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
)

//somewhere anywhere else in your code
context.read<PagesCubit>().selectPage(index);
```

**Note:** Don't handle navigation inside of your button, unless you know the page you want to navigate to. You'll end up copying and pasting a lot of code. Instead, pull the navigation up a level (wrapped around your `Column` for example) and manage the navigation there. You can do this because BLoC allows you to move the code anywhere within the tree that it is providing your bloc.